# How to Post RGB Data in React?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I'm making a system that can control home electrical equipment on the web.
Backend is ready,
It implements RGB picker for the light.

However, I got error.
[image]

```
POST xxx.com/turn_on 422
```

When I choose a color, I can see those variables in the console

```
   const red = rgb_color["red"]
   const green = rgb_color["green"]
   const blue = rgb_color["blue"]
```

so variables are nothing problem I guess.
I guess this section is not good but I don't know hot fix it.

```
      {
        entity_id: entity_id, 
        rgb_color: [red, green, blue],
        brightness: brightness_value
      },
```

By the way, I can get through it in Postman.
[image]

This is Whole code

**LightDetailCondo.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, onClick} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import ic_light from "../../images/icons/ic_light.png"

import hexRgb from 'hex-rgb';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const LightDetailCondo = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [light, setLight] = useState([]);

  const { entity_id } = useParams();

  const [brightness_value, setBrightnessValue] = useState();
  const [hex_value, setHexValue] = useState();

  const rgb_color = hexRgb(hex_value);

  const red = rgb_color["red"]
  const green = rgb_color["green"]
  const blue = rgb_color["blue"]


  const handleSliderChange = (e) => {
    lightOn(e.target.value)
    setBrightnessValue(e.target.value)
  }

  const lightOn = async(data) => {
    await axios.post('xxx.com/turn_on',
      {
        entity_id: entity_id, 
        rgb_color: [red, green, blue],
        brightness: brightness_value
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('Turn on!');
        getDevices();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Turn on Missed!');
      });
  }

const getDevices = async(data) => {
  await axios.get('xxx.com/device_list',
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
      },
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result.data)
      setLight(result.data.attributes.light);  
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getDevices();
    }, []);

console.log(light)
console.log(brightness_value)
console.log(rgb_color)
console.log(rgb_color["red"])
console.log(rgb_color["green"])
console.log(rgb_color["blue"])
console.log(hex_value)


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row mx-auto text-center">
          <>
            {light.filter(c => c.entity_id === entity_id).map((item,i) => 
              <div key={i} className="col-12">
                <div className="box h-100">
                <p>{item.room_name}</p>
                <p>{item.entity_id}</p>
                <p>{item.brightness}</p>
                <img className="" src={ic_light_off} />
                <input type="range" name="speed" min="0" max="100" 
                value={brightness_value} onChange={handleSliderChange}></input><br></br>
                <input type="color" name="favorite_color"
                onChange={handleSliderChange}></input>
                <br></br>
                <Link to={`/discover_condo`} className='btn btn-primary col-4'>Back</Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}

          </>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default LightDetailCondo;
```

Comment: You can ask your backend partner because the 422 code is a backend error, and you need to know what request body you need to send.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the bod of your post request before sending it ?
I think it might help us understand what's going ons as an error 422 means that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct.

```
const lightOn = async(data) => {
console.log("Body sent to server", {
    entity_id: entity_id, 
    rgb_color: [red, green, blue],
    brightness: brightness_value
  })
await axios.post('xxx.com/turn_on',
  {
    entity_id: entity_id, 
    rgb_color: [red, green, blue],
    brightness: brightness_value
  },
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
    },
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log('Turn on!');
    getDevices();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('Turn on Missed!');
  });
```

}